# Best way to compare 2 colums in google sheets and then email mismatched data

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that is the answer sheet to a form sent to students for registration purposes. A= Timestamp B= Email address of student c= Students answer D= All emails of invited students What i need to achieve is column B to check if the email exists in column D and if so move the cell to column E. If it moves it would leave a gap so I would need it to move and then move cells up by 1. I can then import the cells into another sheet to see only the students who have not replied or is there a way to email those automatically.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XfyKP5EbxoGYOiWgPiRWA_OvPGN9hOjICXp_iuJrwIg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you share the research you have done till now?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the following:

- Remove values from column D that also exist in column B (shift up values so that no blank cells are kept).
- Send emails to the resulting column D values.

If that's the case, you can do the following with Apps Script: [create a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) by selecting `Tools > Script editor` and copy and execute the following code (check inline comments):

```js
function sendEmailsToNonRespondents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Get spreadsheet
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Your sheet name (change if necessary)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); // Get sheet
  var allAddresses = getColumnValues(sheet, 2, 4); // Get non-empty values from column D (excluding row 1)
  var respondents = getColumnValues(sheet, 2, 2); // Get non-empty values from column B (excluding row 1)
  var nonRespondents = allAddresses.filter(address => !respondents.includes(address)).map(address => [address]); // Retrieve list of emails of non-respondents
  sheet.getRange("D2:D").clearContent(); // Clear old column D content (excluding row 1)
  sheet.getRange(2, 4, nonRespondents.length, 1).setValues(nonRespondents); // Write new column D content (non-respondents)
  nonRespondents.forEach(email => {
    var subject = "Mail subject"; // Change according to your preferences
    var body = "Mail body"; // Change according to your preferences
    MailApp.sendEmail(email[0], subject, body); // Send email for each non-respondent
  });
}

function getColumnValues(sheet, firstRow, colIndex) {
  return sheet.getRange(firstRow, colIndex, sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1, 1).getValues().filter(value => value[0] != "").map(value => value[0]);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample, no data is moved to column E (I don't see why that's necessary, since the respondent emails are recorded in column B anyway).
- In this sample, every time the script runs, all content in column D gets removed, and the filtered content is written again, instead of just removing the undesired values.

#### Reference:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)